# Malformed request to AzureAD

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory

I have a Spring boot application, and have succeeded in logging in with AzureAD through Oauth2/Openid connect. I am able to see information of the user from the OAuth2User.

Now, using the flow documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user , I try to get an accesstoken starting from my authorization token. I do this as follows, using the Apache httpclient:

```
@GetMapping("current")
 public UserTo getCurrentUserInformation() throws IOException {
  OAuth2AuthenticationToken auth = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(auth.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), auth.getName());
  String accessToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();


  try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
    List<NameValuePair> form = new ArrayList<>();
    form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "<configured client-secret>"));
    form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
    form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", accessToken));
    form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "<configured client_id>"));
    form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", "group.read.all user.read"));
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(form, Consts.UTF_8);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token");
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    System.out.println("Executing request " + httpPost.getRequestLine());

    // Create a custom response handler
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = response -> {
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
            return responseEntity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity) : null;
        } else {
            throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
        }
    };
    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(responseBody);
    return null;
}
```

Evidently, ;  and <tenant_id> correspond are the actual values.

As you can see in the log of the actual http call below, I get a *AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid*

```
>> POST /<tenant-idb/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
>> Content-Length: 840
>> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>> Host: login.microsoftonline.com
>> Connection: Keep-Alive
>> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/11)
>> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>> "POST /<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 840[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: login.microsoftonline.com[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/11)[\r][\n]"
>> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> "client_secret=GQflwHG.....m&grant_type=authorization_code&code=PAQAB......&client_id=.....&scope=group.read.all+user.read"
<< "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
<< "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache[\r][\n]"
<< "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
<< "Expires: -1[\r][\n]"
<< "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
<< "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
<< "P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"[\r][\n]"
<< "x-ms-request-id: f5f093c0-caba-4c0c-ba68-3ccd5b424c00[\r][\n]"
<< "x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.11021.14 - DUB1 ProdSlices[\r][\n]"
<< "Set-Cookie: fpc=Al-xwX2rJtFLqoSZskQjAWU; expires=Tue, 13-Oct-2020 22:50:23 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None[\r][\n]"
<< "Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly[\r][\n]"
<< "Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly[\r][\n]"
<< "Date: Sun, 13 Sep 2020 22:50:22 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Length: 485[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
<< "{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: f5f093c0-caba-4c0c-ba68-3ccd5b424c00\r\nCorrelation ID: a174fae6-35ca-45ae-8a80-cc53c5d86119\r\nTimestamp: 2020-09-13 22:50:23Z","error_codes":[9002313],"timestamp":"2020-09-13 22:50:23Z","trace_id":"f5f093c0-caba-4c0c-ba68-3ccd5b424c00","correlation_id":"a174fae6-35ca-45ae-8a80-cc53c5d86119","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"}"
<< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
<< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
<< Pragma: no-cache
<< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
<< Expires: -1
<< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
<< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<< P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
<< x-ms-request-id: f5f093c0-caba-4c0c-ba68-3ccd5b424c00
<< x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.11021.14 - DUB1 ProdSlices
<< Set-Cookie: fpc=Al-xwX2rJtFLqoSZskQjAWU; expires=Tue, 13-Oct-2020 22:50:23 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
<< Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
<< Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
<< Date: Sun, 13 Sep 2020 22:50:22 GMT
<< Content-Length: 485
```

Can anybody enlighten me on why my request is erroneous?

Answer (score 0):

The authorization code that you used to request the access token is wrong, and because you are using the auth-code-flow, you are also missing the redirect uri parameter, please refer to [auth-code-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

```
@GetMapping("current")
 public UserTo getCurrentUserInformation() throws IOException {
  OAuth2AuthenticationToken auth = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(auth.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), auth.getName());
  string authorizationCode = "<the authorization code>";


  try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
    List<NameValuePair> form = new ArrayList<>();
    form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "<configured client-secret>"));
    form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
    form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", authorizationCode));
    form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "<configured redirect_uri>"));
    form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "<configured client_id>"));
    form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", "group.read.all user.read"));
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(form, Consts.UTF_8);
    .....
}
```

***Update***

You can copy the following code into your browser's address bar to request authorization code.
Be careful not to copy the last parameters of the code which are &session_state and &state when your request is successful.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={{client id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri={your redirect_uri}
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Do you have any idea where to get the authorization code from then? Or even how it would look like/how I can recognise it? The accesscode I'm currently usually starts with PAQABAAAAAA... and is about 750 characters long. It seems to be the only code I can find in the security context. The only other code I find is the idToken (OidcIdToken), which typically starts with eyJ0eX.... and is about 1350 characters long, which doesn't seem to be right either.

Comment: Also, I was actually under the impression that I was using the On-Behalf-Of flow: spring redirects the (angular) frontend to microsoft, it authenticates and calls spring again, this time with the authentication cookie which the spring security context makes available. I now have an authenticated user, and try to call APIs from microsoft (on the page shown as the "Middle tier access token request"

Comment: @YvesV.Hi,I updated my answer and from the code you provided you are using ath-code-flow. OBO flow needs one client-side and two api-side,you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow .

Comment: Perhaps my setup is unclear? I have a client-server app: angular frontend, spring boot backend. The frontend requests a page, gets redirected by the backend to microsoft login, logs in, and the redirect from MS sets a cookie. The frontend redoes the call, this time with the sessionid and is authenticated by spring-security. All this works, and in my rest service I can retrieve the user data. I find the openid token and can decode it on https://jwt.ms/. However, the accesstoken I get from my spring security context does not parse on jwt.ms and is clearly invalid (PAQABAAAAAAAGV.....)

Comment: With your call I can indeed request an accesstoken in the browser, but I don't really see how that should be integrated in the above flow. Does my backend have to make this call??? In a previous spring-boot version, I could retrieve the token from OAuth2AuthenticationDetails (which was retrieved by getDetails of SecurityContectHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()), but in recent versions this is now a WebAuthenticationDetails object without this information.

Comment: @YvesV.Hi ,are you still asking for help?Sorry, I don't know what you mean, I found an example of java's auth code flow, which you can refer to.https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp